# Image convolution, error generating filtered image

Tags: c, image, filter

I adapted the code from Rosetta Code, but i'm getting just white or yellow images, instead of a filtered image.

The image i'm using is lena.ppm.

main:  with one filter example and some parameters, that were on the site

```
double sobel_emboss_kernel[3*3] = {
    -1., -2., -1.,
    0.,  0.,  0.,
    1.,  2.,  1.,
  };

  const double filter_params[2*4] = {
    1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.5,
    9.0, 0.0
  };



ImageRGB *imagergb;
ImageRGB *rgb_filtered;
imagergb = readRGB("lena.ppm");
rgb_filtered=filter_rgb(imagergb, sobel_emboss_kernel, 1, filter_params[2], filter_params[3]);
writeRGB("resultado_rgb.ppm",imagergb);
```

filter function and pixel functions (my struct is corretly implemented):

```
ImageRGB *filter_rgb(ImageRGB *img, double *K, int Ks, double divisor, double offset){

  ImageRGB *img_filtered;
  unsigned int ix, iy, l;

  int kx, ky;
  double cp[3];
  int pixel_red,pixel_green,pixel_blue;

  img_filtered = (ImageRGB*)malloc(sizeof(ImageRGB));
  img_filtered->width = img->width;
  img_filtered->height = img->height;
  img_filtered->pixels = (colorPixel*)malloc(img->width * img->height * sizeof(colorPixel));

  for(ix=0; ix < img->width; ix++) {
    for(iy=0; iy < img->height; iy++) {

      cp[0] = cp[1] = cp[2] = 0.0;
      for(kx=-Ks; kx <= Ks; kx++) {
        for(ky=-Ks; ky <= Ks; ky++) {
          pixel_red,pixel_green,pixel_blue=getPixelRGB(img,ix+kx,iy+ky);
          cp[0] += (K[(kx+Ks) + (ky+Ks)*(2*Ks+1)]/divisor) * (double)pixel_red + offset;
          cp[1] += (K[(kx+Ks) + (ky+Ks)*(2*Ks+1)]/divisor) * (double)pixel_green + offset;
          cp[2] += (K[(kx+Ks) + (ky+Ks)*(2*Ks+1)]/divisor) * (double)pixel_blue + offset;

        }
      }
      for(l=0; l<3; l++)
        cp[l] = (cp[l]>255.0) ? 255.0 : ((cp[l]<0.0) ? 0.0 : cp[l]) ;
      put_pixel_unsafe(img_filtered, ix, iy, (int)cp[0], (int)cp[1], (int)cp[2]);

    }
  }
  return img_filtered;
}




void *put_pixel_unsafe(ImageRGB *img,int x,int y,int red,int green,int blue){
    unsigned int ofs;
    ofs = (y * img->width) + x;
    img->pixels[ofs].red = red;
    img->pixels[ofs].green = green;
    img->pixels[ofs].blue = blue;
}



int getPixelRGB(ImageRGB *imageRGB,int x, int y){
  if (x < 0 || x > imageRGB->width || y < 0 || y > imageRGB->height){
    return 0;
  }
  unsigned int position = (y * imageRGB->width) + x;
  return imageRGB->pixels[position].red,imageRGB->pixels[position].green,imageRGB->pixels[position].blue;
}
```

What im doing wrong?

Comment: What do you expect this: `pixel_red,pixel_green,pixel_blue=getPixelRGB(img,ix+kx,iy+ky);` to do?

Comment: `pixel_red, pixel_green, pixel_blue = getPixelRGB(img,ix+kx,iy+ky);` -- C does not have tuples like for example Python. You should probably return a struct of three values here. (The syntax is correct, though, but it doesn't do what you want.)

Comment: yes, i changed it! Thank you!

Comment: regarding; `1.,  2.,  1.,`  The final comma ',' is only valid/needed if compiling `ANSI` C

Comment: OT:  regarding this kind of statement: `img_filtered = (ImageRGB*)malloc(sizeof(ImageRGB));`  In C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.   Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest removing that cast.

Comment: regarding; `img_filtered->pixels = (colorPixel*)malloc(img->width * img->height * sizeof(colorPixel));`  This is failing to take into account that the width of a line of the image, in pixels, is always a multiple of 4

Comment: regarding: `for(ix=0; ix < img->width; ix++) {`   This is failing to take into account that the width of a line of the image, in pixels, is always a multiple of 4

Comment: regarding: `pixel_red,pixel_green,pixel_blue=getPixelRGB(img,ix+kx,iy+ky);`  This is nonsense.  Only one variable can be the recipient of an assignment

Comment: regarding: `ofs = (y * img->width) + x;`  This is failing to take into account that the width of a line of the image, in pixels, is always a multiple of 4

Comment: the posted code fails to take into account that a pixel (depending on the image) can be anywhere from 1 to 4 bytes

Comment: regarding: `unsigned int position = (y * imageRGB->width) + x;`   This is failing to take into account that the width of a line of the image, in pixels, is always a multiple of 4

Comment: regarding: `return imageRGB->pixels[position].red,imageRGB->pixels[position].green,imageRGB->pixels[position].blue;`  This does not do what you expect.  Suggest init each of fields of the pixel, then return the pixel, do not try to return a bunch of individual fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your line:

```c
pixel_red,pixel_green,pixel_blue=getPixelRGB(img,ix+kx,iy+ky);
```

This does not do what you may think! It simply assigns the value returned by `getPixelRGB` to a ***single*** variable, `pixel_blue` (the other two are left unchanged).

Form what I can gather, you need to assign the respective `R`, `G` and `B` values to each of the three variables in that line. One way of doing this (though not *necessarily* the best or most efficient) is to declare separate `getPixelX` functions for each colour channel:

```c
int getPixelR(ImageRGB *imageRGB,int x, int y){ // Red channel
  if (x < 0 || x > imageRGB->width || y < 0 || y > imageRGB->height) return 0;
  unsigned int position = (y * imageRGB->width) + x;
  return imageRGB->pixels[position].red;
}

int getPixelG(ImageRGB *imageRGB,int x, int y){ // Red channel
  if (x < 0 || x > imageRGB->width || y < 0 || y > imageRGB->height) return 0;
  unsigned int position = (y * imageRGB->width) + x;
  return imageRGB->pixels[position].green;
}

int getPixelB(ImageRGB *imageRGB,int x, int y){ // Red channel
  if (x < 0 || x > imageRGB->width || y < 0 || y > imageRGB->height) return 0;
  unsigned int position = (y * imageRGB->width) + x;
  return imageRGB->pixels[position].blue;
}
```

You would then call each of these functions separately for each value:

```c
pixel_red = getPixelR(img,ix+kx,iy+ky);
pixel_green = getPixelG(img,ix+kx,iy+ky);
pixel_blue = getPixelB(img,ix+kx,iy+ky);
```

Comment: I think the intention is to return the R, G and B values and not to assign the same value to all three. The comma-operator construct appears in the `return` statement of `getPixelRGB` as well.

Comment: @MOehm OK, I can see that now. I'll edit my answer (but will take a few minutes).

Comment: @ali The problem is, the answer I first posted was almost certainly wrong! See the latest version.